# QuickBooks POS 2013

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to figure out what is SDK I need to create a hook into QuickBooks POS 2013.  The QuickBooks POS SDK seems to only support up to version 10.0.  I am wondering if I need to use the QuickBooks SDK version 13.0 and not the POS SDK?  I have never programmed QuickBooks but I have a program in C# I need to write now.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QuickBooks Point of Sale SDK available for download/documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0260_pos

Supports *all versions* of QuickBooks Point of Sale.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure when I read the page since it doesn't really state it covers all previous versions.